# How to disable Swagger ui documentation in Fastapi for production server?

Tags: python, fastapi

How to disable Swagger ui documentation in Fastapi for production server?
i need disable fastapi documentation

Answer (score 25):

[Construct your app with `docs_url=None` and `redoc_url=None`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#docs-urls) and FastAPI won't mount those endpoints.

```
app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the env variable `OPENAPI_URL` to an empty string. Find more details in the [FastAPI-Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/conditional-openapi/#conditional-openapi-from-settings-and-env-vars).

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class Settings(BaseSettings):
     OPENAPI_URL: str = "/openapi.json"

     model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
         env_file=".env.prod", env_file_encoding="utf-8",case_sensitive=True
     )


settings = Settings()

app = FastAPI(openapi_url=settings.OPENAPI_URL)
```

`.env.prod`:

```
OPENAPI_URL=""
```